# Unity keystore problems : Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, digital-signature

im trying add a unity key for my android app bundle game
cmd line asking me allies password and when i write the password everytime this error coming:

Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding
....

i tried download openjdk20, i set my enviroment, i set java_home, i set path and nothing changed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWSfi.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfHCT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.